# How to implode many available to one available using loop for?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, implode

How to implode many available to one available using loop for ?

i have many available like

```
$var_1 = one;
$var_2 = two;
$var_3 = three;
$var_4 = four;
$var_5 = five;
$var_6 = six;
$var_7 = seven;
$var_8 = eight;
$var_9 = nine;
$var_10 = ten;
$var_11 = eleven;
```

and then i want to implode to one available

```
$all_data = one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,
```

but i want to using loop for like this

```
for ( $i=1;$i<12;$i++ )
{
$all_data = ${var_$i}.",";
}
```

how can i do ? thank you for every comment ^^

Comment: Using an array would be *ssoooooo* much better than this

Comment: if i want to create array from available like this , How can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$all_data = implode(',', array($var_1, $var_2, ..., $var_11));
```

Any time you find yourself creating a bunch of variables with numeric names like this, say to yourself: "I really should be using an array". There's almost never a good reason for this type of programming.

For the `for` loop you're trying to write, see the PHP documentation on [Variable Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$all_data = '';
for ($i = 1; $i < 12; $i++) {
    $all_data .= ${'var_'.$i} . ',';
}
```

Comment: thank you , i want to use loop for because i have many available
how can i do ?

^^

Comment: While this is the correct answer, we need to stress, as John Conde did above; Chances are you should not be implementing it this way. You should be using arrays.

Comment: @user3141230 1There reason you should use an array is because you have many variables.

Comment: if i want to create array from available like this , How can i do ?

Comment: Don't you see it in the first line of my answer? Or you could use a loop similar to the one creating `$all_data`, but instead of concatenating to a string it pushes onto an array (you know how to do that, don't you?).